# Linux screen managment on root through php user

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

I want to make a script that would run something in `screen` on root user. This has to be done through php `system()` function therefore I need to find out way to sudo to root and pass a password, all using PHP.

Comment: If this script is being run by calling it from a website I am pretty sure this isn't going to work because the www-data (or whatever user your webserver is using) won't be able to 'sudo' to run something as root.

Comment: @gnur: That depends on `sudo` configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* need to `sudo` from PHP (not recommended), it's best to only allow specific commands and not require password for them.

For example, if PHP is running as the `apache` user, and you need to run `/usr/bin/myapp`, you could add the following to `/etc/sudoers` (or wherever sudoers is):

```
apache ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:NOEXEC: /usr/bin/myapp
```

This means that user `apache` can run `/usr/bin/myapp` as `root` without password, but the app can't execute anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there must be a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to accomplish than whatever mechanism you're trying to create.

If you simply want to write messages from a php script to a single `screen` session somewhere, try this:

**In php**

Open a file with append-write access:

```
$handle = fopen("/var/log/from_php", "wb");
```

Write to your file:

```
fwrite($handle, "Sold another unit to " . $customer . "\n");
```

**In your screen session**

```
tail -F /var/log/from_php
```

If you can't just run `tail` in a screen session, you can use the `write(1)` utility to write messages to different terminals. See `write(1)` and `mesg(1)` for details on this mechanism. (I don't like it as much as the logfile approach, because that is durable and can be searched later. But I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, so this is another option that might work better than `tail -F` on a log file.)